# How do I test/check if the limit exists for $f(x) = \lvert x-2\rvert$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given 
$$\frac {df}{dx}(x)=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to0}\frac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x},$$
how do I express using the above expression or test if the limit exists for  $$ f(x) = \lvert x-2\rvert?$$

Comment: You can consider different cases, when  $x>2$, $$x=2$$, $x<2$, and find the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given function can be written as:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x-2 & \text{ if } x\geq2 \\ 
2-x & \text{ if } x<2
\end{cases}$

Can you do it from here?